What is the equivalent of "Inside Track"?
I was looking for the equivalent of the sporting idiom "inside track" in French, which carries with it the idea of advantage of position.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Être en position avantageuse or avoir / avoir l'avantage would probably work whether you use the phrase literally (as in a racing context) or figuratively, but there are several better translations according the context in which you are using the phrase. So, as asked, you really should rephrase your question. How do I ask a good question?.

Welcome to fr.SE! It's hard to tell if we have an exact translation. Courir à la corde or Être côté corde is nominally for horse racing, however it is often used figuratively. An example phrase would help, with the translation you're not satisfied with.

We use a similar idiom in French: prendre la corde, tenir la corde, être à la corde.

TLFi: Corde
[...]
♦ Expressions
Tenir la corde. [En parlant d'un coureur] Être placé près du bord intérieur de la piste; au figuré être dans une bonne position.

Oui, patron, je crois que nous ferons des affaires exceptionnelles et de grands bénéfices, car la Vénus de Milo, pour cette saison, tient la corde et ne la lâchera pas (Avenel, Calicots, 1866, p. 159).
Comme Mme Molé (car c'est elle qui tient la corde en ce moment) vient de partir, il est tout désemparé (Proust, Sodome et Gomorrhe, 1922, p. 691).
Prendre un virage à la corde. [En parlant d'un automobiliste] Le prendre le plus près possible de la courbe intérieure.


Wikipedia Tenir la corde

(Sens figuré) Avoir l’avantage, la préférence ; se trouver en situation avantageuse de gagner.

Ainsi s’explique la déchéance extraordinairement rapide d’une science où nous avons jadis tenu la corde avec les Bichat, les Laënnec, les Duchenne de Boulogne, les Morel de Rouen, les Claude Bernard, les Charcot et les Potain ; sans compter le grand Pasteur, qui est à part, mais dont l’Institut est lui aussi, à l’heure actuelle, en complète décomposition. — (Léon Daudet, Souvenirs littéraires – Devant la douleur, Grasset, 1915, réédition Le Livre de Poche, page 101)
Le Point est même en mesure d’en donner le titre (au moins celui qui tient la corde) : Ma vérité. Pour quelqu’un qui, comme l’autre jour à la télévision, n’arrête pas de raconter des craques, c’est un beau titre, je trouve. — (Alain Rémond, Le livre, lui, ne ment pas, dans Marianne n° 772 du 4 février 2012, page 98)
Aucun de ces schémas ne tient pour l’instant la corde. — (Ivan Valerio, Coronavirus : les cinq sujets sur lesquels Macron doit s’exprimer sur BTMTV, Nextinteractive. Mis en ligne le 13 avril 2020)


Here is an explanation of the origin of this corde:

On trouve une autre position avantageuse avec l’expression tenir la corde. Celle-ci nous vient des courses de chevaux. Il arrivait que la course consistât à se rendre le plus rapidement possible d’un point à un autre, mais assez vite, il s’est agi de faire le tour d’un espace délimité par une lice ou simplement une corde, qui marquait le bord intérieur de la piste. Le cavalier qui occupait la position la plus proche de la corde avait moins de distance à parcourir que les autres.
Source: Académie française

I'm surprised to hear that some native French speakers might be unfamiliar with this idiom as it has been in use since the 19th century and is still common, especially in the news (bold mine).

Qui tient la corde à gauche pour devenir Premier ministre? BFMTV répond à vos questions BFM, July 2024


Retrait de Joe Biden : face à Donald Trump, Kamala Harris tient la corde L'Humanité July 2024


Qui est Aaron Taylor-Johnson, l’acteur qui tient la corde pour incarner le prochain James Bond ? Le Figaro March 2024


Après quatre saisons sous le nom de "Ligue 1 Uber Eats", le championnat de France de football va très probablement changer de patronyme. Le nouveau sponsor sera annoncé le 21 mars prochain. McDonald's semble tenir la corde. La Montagne, March 2024


I don't think this would work when inside track is used figuratively, as in, for instance: "Being the CEO's nephew he really had the inside track for the job." But, I agree, the question not being clear we don't really know what the OP is asking for.

@None Je suis surpris par tes deux remarques. Même si elle mériterait d'être plus étoffée, la question me semble quand même très claire. Avoir un avantage lié à la position dans un contexte sportif correspond précisément à tenir la corde et c'est une expression couramment utilisée au sens figuré. Seul conservateur notoire à avoir soutenu le « leave », il tient la corde pour le poste de Premier ministre.

Je n'avais jamais rencontré tenir la corde au sens figuré ! Alors que je connais have the inside track en anglais. C'est un plaisir d'apprendre à tout âge.... Au temps pour moi.

Thank you for taking the time to reply. I write publicity materials for an English language school in France and wanted to do an Olympic Games themed post. I thought about using the idea that English lessons would give students the inside track, but I couldn't find an equivalent idiom

@user35862 Thanks for the details. It's not to late to edit your question and add them. Tenir la corde is usually said about a person alone or a team but rarely about a group of people. UJM's une longueur d'avance (+1) is less literal than tenir la corde but sounds a better idiom in the case you describe.

A similar sports-related idiom is une longeur d’avance, which translates fairly well to one step ahead:

En matière de semiconducteurs, l’entreprise MachinTruc a une longueur d’avance sur ses concurrents. Company SomeThing is one step ahead of its competitors when it comes to semiconductors.


Elle lui a parlé toute la journée, elle a une longueur d’avance sur moi pour le séduire. She spent the whole day talking to him, she is one step ahead of me to seduce him.

That idiom does not imply that the better position is due to insider knowledge (for instance, proximity to the boss for a promotion, etc.). However, it is much better-known than the other suggestion of « tenir la corde », which has (I believe) the same drawback of describing the situation without explaining how it came about.

Very useful, thank you.

In the literal sense, when running a distance of between 200m and 1000m, each athlete is assigned to a lane or track.

Lane/track translates to couloir.
Inside track would be couloir intérieur.
Likewise, outside track would be couloir extérieur.


Note that because in that context all track lenghts are identical, being assigned the couloir intérieur is not an advantage for the runners.

@jlliagre not sure, yes distance is the same, but inside tracker can see (at least at beginning of race) others, while outside tracker can't.

Le couloir numéro 1 (la corde) est le pire à cause de son rayon de courbure que le coureur doit compenser. Quand il y a plus de couloirs que de coureurs, c'est d'abord celui-là qu'on n'attribue pas. cf. qualifications du 200 m au JO de Paris ce soir.
